# DOMPDF isn't working with ajax call from view in codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, dompdf

I am trying to save a specific div from my view to pdf by sending that div's html to controller `function pdf` using by submitting a form in which a hidden input field  value is setas the desired div content.  the pdf is generating but it doesn't shows input fields data and style is distorted

here is my javascript code

```
$(document).change(function() {
 // alert( "Change" );

  var $html = $('div.printable').html();
  $('input[name="content"]').val($html);


});
```

here is my **controller** function to generate pdf .

```
 public function pdf()
{     $html = $this->input->post('content').$this->load->view('_partials/footer','',true);

     $this->load->library('pdfgenerator'); 
     $jobs = $this->invoice_model->getJob();
   $this->data['job'] = $jobs;
    $this->page_sub_heading = 'Add New Invoice';


  $filename = 'Invoice_'.time();
$this->pdfgenerator->generate($html, $filename, true, 'tabloid', 'landscape');


}
```

here is the **view form** which call mycontroller/pdf on submit

```
<?php echo form_open("mycotroller/pdf"); ?>
<input type="hidden" name="content" >
<button style="margin-top: 10px;" type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary 
 ">pdf</button>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Comment: My experience with DOMPDF is that if your HTML isn't well formed, it won't produce the PDF. Also, if you are using tables and a table cell would be half on one page and half on the other, it would produce an error. You might take the HTML you expect DOMPDF to use and run it manually, and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks for you response.  I managed to create pdf but now styles and input fields aren't rendered correctly  i am only creating a pdf of specific div and sending it to controller using form-submit. I have updated the question . kindly let me know if you know anything about this issue